# 'gopls.go_get_package' failed in vscode installing

Tags: go

Command 'gopls.go_get_package' failed: Error: err: exit status 1: stderr: template: main:1:9: executing "main" at <.Module.Path>: nil pointer evaluating *modinfo.ModulePublic.Path .

Comment: Add your GO version, operational system

Comment: go1.18.3 darwin/amd64